# Does image processing in python using pytesseract gives correct output always?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract contents of an image in python using pytesseract. I got the output, but for some images, I am unable to extract the contents.
Example,

[image]

I am getting the following wrong output:

```
‘Happiness is. a choice,
lo Tmest Mella A egy
Ce Re
gran
Tate Tae
Manta tan oa ae)

Cg

ed
unas
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Pytesseract works best for text in simpler fonts. The picture you have given is cursive, and therefore makes it hard for pytesseract to distinguish between letters. That is why it does not work properly. You can try changing the parameters in pytesseract for slightly better results, but I highly doubt whether you can get the complete text.

You can refer this link, if you want to improve your results: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/

Comment: I have downloaded and run the code mentioned by your link. Can you please tell me how should I execute it?

Comment: I advise you to go through the blog first, as I cannot explain better than that. pyimagesearch.com is, if not the best, one of the best places to learn what you are trying to do.